# How to get number of rows in a table in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

After sleepless night and run over the stackoverflow I could not find the method (function) that can resolve my probleme.

What I wrote is very harder for the server. Is there any more clever way to resolve this problem?

Here my code:

```
public static int GetIndexLong(string TblName)
{
    int rowsNbr = 0;
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
    {
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TblName, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ++rowsNbr;
                }
            }
            return rowsNbr;
        }
    }
}
```

It does the job but I know it's not the good way.

Working with C# Express 2008 on .NET 4.0.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
```

In your code it would be like:

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TblName, conn))
```

or if you want to return the number of rows you may probably try this too:-

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TblName, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: When I do by this way I don't how to retreive the rows number.

Comment: Didnt get your question properly but is this what you want? com.CommandText = "select @@ROWCOUNT";
        var totalRow = com.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Thank you very much this last updated has worked and I added to my program.

Comment: @IsmailGunes:- Do accept this as an answer if that helped you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The right query for the job is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM + TblName
```

(But this really has nothing to do with C#.)

The C# code replacement in your case would be:

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TblName, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working. . But the same way solutions that I've found by your way (executescalar) was not working. Your's working perfectly. By the way I've tried  SELECT count(*) but I did not know how to retreive it's answer to your remark.

Comment: @IsmailGunes: Feel free to Accept the answer then.